# 2sxc: DNN Portal Templates and 2SexyContent

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

Does 2SexyContent completely support being included in a DNN Portal Template? Our site is a blogging site that needs very specific content layouts and setup. If I were to create a template and setup for 2SexyContent and then include it in a portal template and then applied that template to a new portal, would all of the 2SexyContent setup and templates be carried over completely? (This would not carry over content, it needs to be a fresh and empty instance). I ask because this particular project requires that we quickly and efficiently create portals on the fly without having to go through all the module settings every time.

Comment: I would love to know this as well

Answer (score 0):

As of now, this can be done cleanly and effectively - but not in one single step. The reason is that this has various complexities incl. that apps must be installed on each portal and that these app-instances must be wired to the page where they appear, + there can be language issues and more.

But fret not, it's been prepared for and tested :). There's even a checklist - check out http://2sxc.org/en/Learn/Copy-Duplicate-an-entire-Site